Nanopi neo (Allwinner H3) does not boot from MMC any more
I have a device called Nanopi Neo Core with Allwinner H3 processor on board, 512MB of RAM and eMMC. I broke it and unable to find what to do to restore it.
Originally it came with the Armbian preinstalled on the MMC, and it was booting. I develop for Openwrt, compiling the whole bundle of U-boot + kernel using sources from official openwrt repo. I was writing resulting image onto the SD-card, and the device was booting properly from it.
Now I needed to install the openwrt with all its stuff onto the MMC of the device. Here's my first post where I was recommended to follow specific steps. Unfortunately, it did not work because I had to get parts by pieces, and some were not locatable in the compile tree.
So I decided just to write SD-card image onto the MMC. I am still not sure if it was correct action or not - have seen somewhere that SD-card images must be converted to MMC images but seen no details on why. Found this one which shows that boot areas are separate to the "user area", therefore writing SD-card image in the "user area" should have worked. But it did not, and I have got MMC installation broke.
Current state: if I do not insert SD-card with compiled openwrt image, I get the following screen

but if I put SD-card in, then system boots into the openwrt. It first loads this U-boot copy as on the pic, then loads it again saying that it is copyright by Allwinner technology, and then boots the kernel. I can track the versions actually booting by the build date displayed.
More to say, with SD-card installed, when it boots into second U-boot copy and I interrupt the process, I can switch to eMMC and boot openwrt from the eMMC.
Therefore 'kernel stuff' is alive on the eMMC, the problem is first time U-boot instance trying to boot from MMC2 (which I guess is an eMMC) but then unexpectedly saying about missing "MMC 1" device (which must be an SD-card). This is my educated guess.
What I have done:

originally I tried to follow this guide and as said before had troubles finding respective pieces in the build tree. I went up to repartitioning eMMC.
then I just wrote SD-card image into the eMMC. I am not sure when this ### ERROR ### has started.
then I played with boot0/1 areas of the eMMC, figured out that when I clean them, machine seems to be bricked when SD-card is not installed (nothing on the console), but when I install SD-card it boots openwrt. The strange thing is when I cleaned up first 512MB of the eMMC, it again bricked, therefore the picture in the guide "Working with embedded
MultiMediaCard" is wrong, and "boot areas" are actually a part of the "user area"?
when I write any U-boot (with SPL) into the boot0 area, with no SD-card installed it starts showing this screen as on the pic.
I have downloaded prebuilt Armbian image from FriendlyElec, wrote it to the eMMC using dd, and it does not work in the same way (see pic).
I have downloaded eflasher friendlywrt image, wrote it into the SD-card, and it shows the same message.

It seems to be very good that machine is not dead completely because I still can boot from the SD-card into the openwrt, but I need to boot openwrt from the eMMC when SD-card is not installed, and boot from SD-card when it is in.
My understanding that I am missing some basic understanding of how the things work. There must be some disconnect in the boot chain, and I am unable to figure out where and therefore have no idea where to head.
Any advice or pointer to the appropriate descriptive documentation will be very appreciated. Even more appreciated would be (short) explanation what exactly is going on and where to look into. Thanks!
Some more technical info: I turned on (okay'ed) eMMC in both linux and u-boot. Tried to 'y' some configuration keys related to the MMC boot in the U-boot configuration.
Update: found this page seemingly to be helpful. Looking into the u-boot.cfg file and it has
#define CONFIG_SYS_MMCSD_RAW_MODE_U_BOOT_SECTOR 0x40
#define CONFIG_SYS_MMCSD_RAW_MODE_U_BOOT_DATA_PART_OFFSET 0x10

According to the doc, the initial SPL loader is written into the 8kB offset within the card - offset 0x10 (assuming sector size of 512 bytes). I guess this is the one who says to reset the board - because (assuming) for some reason it can't find U-boot.
According to CONFIG_SYS_MMCSD_RAW_MODE_U_BOOT_SECTOR setting the main U-boot must be located in the sector 0x40 = 32kB offset (0x8000).
Looking into the compiled u-boot-sunxi-with-spl.bin file and see that it starts with loader and signature GON.BT0 U-G and text U-Boot SPL 2023.04-OpenWrt-r24924-0fd3a6c6c6 thus loader must be run as expected - and what we see on the screen up to "reset" message. After the offset 0x8000 in the file I see U-Boot 2023.04-OpenWrt-r24924-0f and then U-Boot 2023.04-OpenWrt-r24924-0fd3a6c6c6 (May 10 2024 - 00:08:23 +0000) Allwinner Technology thus U-boot itself is in place in correct location, and what should have been displayed on its boot is also in place.
So the question is why loader obtained from absolute sector 0x10 is unable to find U-boot executable at the absolute sector 0x10+0x40.
Update: the circuit diagram of the device assumes 8-bit data bus for eMMC

and logically I have put
bus-width = <8>;

into the device tree mmc2 description. However when I issue
mmc bootbus set single_hs x1 x8 /dev/mmcblk1

device is bricked. Reverting back to 4-bit data bus makes primary loader starting and not finding anything on the eMMC with this "reset the board" message.
I have removed questionable lines from the device tree
//  boot_device = <0x00>;
//  bus-width = <4>;

leaving only these in addition to default stuff
pinctrl-names = "default";
pinctrl-0 = <&mmc2_8bit_pins>;
vmmc-supply = <&reg_vcc3v3>;
status = "okay";
non-removable;          /* eMMC is soldered into the board */
cap-mmc-hw-reset;       /* eMMC reset pin is connected to PC16/NAND_DQS/SDC2_RST */

and primary loader still does not find SPL. I have the .dtb file of the original image within the eMMC, and it actually has 8-bit setting for data bus width, therefore I may be simply looking in wrong direction. PPL not finding SPL is not related to device tree at all (which is obtained later in SPL), but the default eMMC x4 data bus mode is critical for reading it in general until proper driver is loaded.
Update: I downloaded friendlywrt-images.tgz and sourced u-boot-sunxi-with-spl.bin from there.
What I do:

boot into openwrt from the sd-card
clean up the eMMC  dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/mmcblk0 bs=1M count=16
make boot partitions writable echo 0 /sys/blocl/mmcblk0bootX/force_ro
clean up boot partitions using dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/mmcblk0bootX
write your u-boot image into the both boot partitions dd if=mnt/u-boot-with-spl,bin of=/dev/mmblk0bootX
make partitions on the eMMC using fdisk: 2048-32767 and 32768-524287
power machine off, remove sd-card, and power it on.

and it shows the following picture -

therefore it is much better now than it was before.

write your u-boot image into the offset 8192 in the eMMC dd if=/mnt/u-boot-with-spl.bin of=/dev/mmcblk0 seek=8192. Unfortunately it makes no difference, and I do not get into the U-boot prompt.

Next, I cloned U-boot from FriendlyElec repository https://github.com/friendlyarm/u-boot/tree/master and got the following result after the configuration, and it does not build.

I tried mainstream U-boot from here, executed the nanopineo defconfig, compiled the image, wrote it to all required locations, and got the same result as original - "reset the board".
Thus the board does NOT support mainstream U-boot, and there must be specific customization for the mainstream U-boot files to allow Nanopi Neo booting from eMMC.
Update: trying to reverse engineer the U-boot SPL code. It seems the list of boot devices is defined on the compile/link time, and there's something wrong with it. So far can't find where it is.
Update: there're no devices in the mmc_devices, print_mmc_devices(',') shows
SUNXI SD/MMC: 0

Update: some progress here. The configuration variable involved is
CONFIG_MMC_SUNXI_SLOT_EXTRA=1

which adds second "slot" for the eMMC (first slot is SD-card). It is required to re-run defconfig after changing the config file for the platform (nanopi_neo_defconfig).
But now I have another problem - it tries to change eMMC's voltage to 1.8V and complains that "card" did not respond to it. Well, not sure as  eMMC is powered from 3V3?
Update: correct driver is being called, but for some reason the only command going through it 0x00 (MMC_CMD_GO_IDLE_STATE), all other commands fail with "timeout" and status code 0x100 which is SUNXI_MMC_RINT_RESP_TIMEOUT bit set.
Update: relatively good news. I bought Sandisk SD-card and tried eflasher with friendlywrt again. Most probably the card I used before is defective. This one booted ok, I run eMMC imaging twice, for only seeing my debug u-boot fail when I remove SD-card. Well, the eflasher is not smart enough to write its u-boot into the mmcblkXbootY partitions, and after I located it on the card and wrote it to these partitions - machine boots off the eMMC like a charm. But there's a piece of shit in the barrel of honey - when I insert SD-card it is not hot-plugged into the system - nothing is block info and in device files.
Conclusion - hardware is alive, something wrong with the "mainstream" U-boot / configuration / drivers for sunxi platform.
Update: sooooo, some more success. I retried doing what had been done before with small modification - I wrote my SD-card openwrt image file into the eMMC not touching eMMC's mmcblkXbootY volumes. Voila, U-boot PPL remainder from the friendlywrt works, starting new U-boot as SPL from my image. There's a problem not booting the OS because boot is not designed for MMC1 (MMC0 only), but if I manually set boot device to 1 and run mmc_boot, it works.
Conclusion: openwrt builder (and generic U-boot) do not (properly) assemble the initial boot loader for the eMMC.
Update: problem solved.

write original sunxi u-boot into the mmcblkXbootY partitions. It has specific settings to support eMMC mainstream u-boot does not have. it is relatively only (I have version 2017.11) but does it matter if it works?
enable eMMC in the device tree for both u-boot and kernel being compiled.
compile openwrt U-boot with the addition of CONFIG_MMC_SUNXI_SLOT_EXTRA=1 into board's defconfig.

